# Docker Django services not communicating

Tags: node.js, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to get my listener service to POST at an API in the app service. The app service is running at 0.0.0.0:8000 and the listener service is trying to post at this address but the data isn't getting added to the db.

I am not sure if I have configured this correctly, help would be much appreciated.

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13.4
    env_file:
      - ./docker/env.db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./docker/env.db
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: bash ./scripts/runserver.sh

  listener:
    image: scooprank_app
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    container_name: listener
    command: npm run listen
    depends_on:
      - app
    restart: always
```

Comment: Check if your app is running on port **8000**

Comment: @NabeelHassan that only means you don't have an EXPOSE directive in your Dockerfile. Your app can open 100 ports and still you won't see them in `docker compose ps`.

Comment: I have checked using the command `docker ps`, and the ports show `0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp` so I think the app is running at port 8000

Comment: @Mihai I have tried `docker port scooprank_app_1`
And I get this:
8000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8000
8000/tcp -> :::8000

Comment: @NabeelHassan persistence is a good thing... sometimes. If you see `0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp` this only means that you have the port mapping declared in docker-compose.yml. This doesn't mean that there is anything listening on port 8000 in the container. Try to GET or POST a request from host to localhost:8000 and check the container logs if you see any trace of it. Also login the container and inside try to ` curl http://localhost:8000`. Based on the response you'll know what you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

If the services are on the same docker-compose file or the same docker network. specify the container name for each service and use the container name in place of the IP address when making GET or POST requests.

if the container name is django_app then in your listener application you can send POST requests to `http://django_app:8000`

Comment: I went into listener bash and tried `curl localhost:8000`, it returned this error message `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused`

Comment: Inside the listener container, `localhost` is the listener container, not the Django container.  Use the Compose service name `app` as a host name.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line that runs manage.py in your runserver script in `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0`, this will bind host 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0.
Important: `allowed_hosts` field in settings.py should not refer to host 0.0.0.0
This worked for me.